# How to automatically retrieve journal ranking and quartile from article list

Tags: publications, bibliometrics, ranking, impact-factor

For a grant application I need to generate a list of my supervisor's publications (hundreds of articles) sorted by date, and for each publication they want impact factor, ranking, and quartile ranking of the journal in the year of publication. If I have to look up this manually it will take me a week. I only have the list of the publications in a CV, not even in a citation manager.

Can anybody help? How can this be done semi-automatically?

Comment: Sorted by date, is trivial if you have a bibtex file. 100 publications are not usually published in 100 journals, but in a lot less, since many people publish in some "favorite" journals.

Comment: Is this your  scholarship? If yes, what does it have anything to do with your supervisor's publication list? Are you sure they want his list, not yours?

Comment: Are you sure they don't want only the 10 most relevant? Or that there isn't a page limit?

Comment: @Alexandros I don't have a bibtex file and they ask info for each year! so it changes every year.

Comment: @scaaahu it's a scholarship part of a joint doctorate, they ask specifically "Qualifications and scientific output of the supervisor" divided by category.

Comment: Have you asked your supervisor? Most authors have their publication (even partly) in bibtex format.

Comment: @Alexandros does bibtex solve the lookup of IF and ranking? I already have their publications sorted by date.

Comment: @Alexandros I'm not convinced, for academia as a whole, that "Most authors have their publication in bibtex format". I've used it all of...once...in my entire career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical place to obtain journal IF and ranking data in a searchable and sorted format is your institution's library. They usually subscribe to commercial ranking services that provide spreadsheets (typically Excel).

If you are a member of the institution (researcher, student) this should be made available to you. Depending on the type of subscription, the library might be reluctant to just share the file via email (in my experience, they are usually allowed to do so). In this case, ask if you can use one of the library's computers to extract the information you need.

Once you have the list of journals sorted, it'll be a bit of legwork to match articles to their respective journals, but a hundred should be doable in a few hours

Comment: @user405 well a question about how to code a script or use Exel macros to automatically match journal metrics to the bibliography should be on topic on other websites on the SE network.